# Java: Generating JSON: Getting exception when try to name object & array

Tags: java, json, javax.json

I`m trying to generate JSON with structure like this:

```
 "rows": [
    {
        "object": {
            "id": "1"
        },
        "values": [
            "111",
            "reg text",
            "11"
        ]
    }
]
```

and here are the code:

```
.writeStartObject()        
.writeStartArray("rows")
    .writeStartObject()       //here i can`t name the object
    .write("id", "'1'@1000")
    .writeEnd()
        .writeStartArray()    //here i can`t name the array
            .write("fax")
            .write("646 555-4567")
        .writeEnd()
.writeEnd()
.writeEnd();
```

When i tried to add object & array headers inside the brackets, i got an exception "Illegal method during JSON generation, not valid in current context IN_ARRAY".
How to generate JSON like mine?

Comment: Please add a tag for which library you are using for json.

Comment: .writeStartArray("rows")
    .writeStartObject()       //here i can`t name the object
    .write("id", "'1'@1000")
    .writeEnd() -- your ending the object, but not the array, that's why you can't name the new array, end the array first

Comment: So I can`t use named array inside named array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code produces the JSON output in your question:

```
generator.writeStartObject()
    .writeStartArray("rows")
        .writeStartObject()
            .writeStartObject("object")
                .write("id", "1")
            .writeEnd()
            .writeStartArray("values")
                .write("111")
                .write("reg text")
                .write("11")
            .writeEnd()
        .writeEnd()
    .writeEnd()
.writeEnd();
```

The first `writeStartObject` begins the anonymous object that's inside the `rows` array. The second `writeStartObject` produces:

```
"object": {
    [...]
}
```

With regards to your comments:

```
.writeStartObject()       //here i can`t name the object

[...]

    .writeStartArray()    //here i can`t name the array
```

You can't specify a name because both the object and array are values in an array. The key is to enclose both of them in an object, and then both of them can (in fact, **must**) have a name.